# In Flutter Is that possible to call API request in firebase Messaging BackgroundHandler?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented chat message app in which user can
reply to chat from push
notification when app is killed/background/foreground.
But when app is in Terminated state API call not work in
firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler.
Its stuck on sendNotification function.

Code to handle background events:

```
 Future<void> 
 firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) 
 async {
    await GetStorage.init();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    //Call HTTP request <Stuck here
    sendNotification(
      personUid,
      title,
      body,
      notificationTypeId,
      chatRoomId,
      userTokenDummy,
      userToken,
      serverKey,
      currentUserId,
      currentUserToken,
    );
  }
```

Here is a code for API request:

```
  sendNotification({
    required String personUid,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required int notificationTypeId,
    String? chatRoomId,
    String? userTokenDummy,
    String? userToken,
    String? serverKey,
    String? currentUserId,
    String? currentUserToken,
  }) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 
  'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'key=$serverKey'
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            "data": <String, dynamic>{
              "title": title,
              "body": body,
              "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
              "id": "1",
              "status": "done",
              "senderId": currentUserId,
              "senderToken": currentUserToken,
              "notificationTypeId": notificationTypeId,
              "chatRoomId": chatRoomId,
            },
            "android": {
              "priority": "high",
            },
            "apns": {
              "headers": {"apns-priority": "10"}
            },
            "to": userToken,
            "content_available": true,
            "mutable-content": 1,
            "priority": "high",
          },
        ),
      );

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      console(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you could try and see if it works, and if it doesn't share your debugging details?

Comment: Yes  i have tried and its not working. its just stuck on http request call.

Comment: Your question should explain what you've done and what's not working the way you expect.  Asking "is it possible" is not really helping us understand what the problem is.

Comment: Yes sure. let me share some code here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can call Http request inside firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler. But make sure that this api is not taking too much time. Because long and intensive tasks impacts on device performance. Also make sure that there is not exception or error in the api which causes the device to freeze.

To make sure that api is not running forever place a timeout in http class.

for more refer to firebase documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive

Comment: in my case API call is not executing.

Comment: Have you annotated your background handler with  @pragma('vm:entry-point') because if it is not annotated with @pragma('vm:entry-point') right above the function declaration then it may be removed during tree shaking for release mode.

Comment: yes i have annotated.

Comment: why are you initializing firebase and get storage here?

Comment: because when app is terminated firebase need to initialize other wise it will not work

Comment: sorry your answer is not helpful to me.

Comment: Ok. One thing that i have in mind is that you can try to run the api in an isolate maybe that could help you.